# HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M182nw on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: printing, laserjet

Will the HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M182nw work on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS? HP will not confirm even though their website says Linux and UNIX are supported OS platforms.

Comment: we do not provide support for hardware.  even if someone tells you it is hplip is a pain to use. getting it to work is also depending on your skillset ;) "even though their website says Linux and UNIX are supported OS platforms." eh, that is not enough to assume it does?!

Comment: What protocol (`IPP`, `PCL`, ...) does the printer support? Re: the MFP part: Linux uses CUPS (`http://localhost:631`) for printing, and SANE for scanning. Read `man -k cups;man -k sane`. Buy the printer if it suits your other needs, return it if it doesn't work. It probably will work, if HP's DRM stuff is Linux compatible. I recently had to return an HP printer because it demanded an unencrypted WiFi as part of Setup.

Answer (score 1):

The HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M182nw works on Ubuntu! This is the same printer I am presently using on my system - Ubuntu 20.04.6. As [Rinzwind mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499130/timeline#comment_2626328) in the comments below your question, it's not easy getting it to work.

You can download the latest version of the HPLIP software from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip by selecting *Ubuntu* in the *Select Distros* drop down box and then clicking *Download HPLIP* right below it.

Once downloaded, to install the software, follow the instructions here:
https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/install/index

---

A much easier alternative would be to install HPLIP using the Synaptic Package Manager than downloading it from the HP website.

If you don't have Synaptic Package Manager installed, run the following commands to install it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install synaptic
```

After that, follow these steps to install HPLIP:

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager.
2. Search for "hplip".
3. Mark the package for installation by clicking the checkbox on the left of it.
4. Click *Apply* to install HPLIP.

I am currently using the older HPLIP version 3.20.3 as you can see in the following screenshot of Synaptic Package Manager:

[image: screenshot of Synaptic showing the version in use]